# How do I prove this winding number is not zero?

Tags: algebraic-topology, winding-number

Let $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow S^1:t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$ be a path.

Let $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ be a continuous map such that $-f(x)=f(-x)$ on $S^1$.

How do I show that the winding number $Wnd(f\circ \alpha,0)$ is not zero?

I have proven this by proving $f$ is not null-homotopic, but I'm now trying to show to prove this directly.

Here's how I tried.

Note that $-(f\circ \alpha)(t)=(f\circ \alpha)(t+1/2)$.

Set $f\circ \alpha = r e^{i\theta}$

If you draw a circle, then it's intuitively clear that $\theta(0)\neq \theta(1)$.

I think this is due to connectedness of $[0,1]$, but I don't know how to prove this rigorously.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Divide [0,1] into two parts [0,1/2] and [1/2,1] and note that $r=1$

Now, let's decompose $\theta$ into two parts so that $\theta=\theta_1 \ast \theta_2$ and set $g_1=e^{i\theta_1} , g_2=e^{i\theta_2}$

Note that $Wnd(f\circ \alpha,0)=Wnd(g_1,0) + Wnd(g_2,0)$ and $g_2=-g_1$

Hence, $e^{\theta_1 - \theta_2} = -1$. Since the range of this is discrete, $\theta_1 = \theta_2 + (2n+1)\pi$

Of course $Wnd(g_1,0)$ is not 0 since $\theta_1(0)\neq \theta_1(1)$

Hence $Wnd(f\circ \alpha,0)= 2 Wnd(g_1,0)$ and thus not 0.

Comment: You need to use braces, `e^{\theta_1}` to get $e^{\theta_1}$ instead of $e^\theta_1$. In your argument, you wrote $\theta_2 = \theta_1 + \pi/2$. You probably meant $\pi$, since $e^{i\pi} = -1$ and $e^{i\pi/2} = i$. But that need not be, consider $f(z) = z^3$. However, the key idea is right, and only a small fix needed. (I'm not saying more now because I think you learn more by finding the flaw and fixing it yourself. Ping me when you have fixed it, or when you don't find the fix and need more guidance.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Correted. Is it correct now?

Comment: That's unfair to edit again while I type my comment and thus making it obsolete ;) Yes, now it is correct.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't notice that :S Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Out of curiosity, did you come up with the argument on your own, or did you take an argument from the literature and modify it to fit this problem?

Comment: @DanielFischer No reference at all. I did it on my own

Comment: That's impressive. Well done.